# Python pandas json 2D array

Tags: pandas

relatively new to pandas, I have a json and python files:

```
{"dataset":{
    "id": 123,
    "data": [["2015-10-16",1,2,3,4,5,6],
             ["2015-10-15",7,8,9,10,11,12],
             ["2015-10-14",13,14,15,16,17]]
}}
```

&

```
import pandas
x = pandas.read_json('sample.json')
y = x.dataset.data
print x.dataset
```

Printing x.dataset and y works fine, but when I go to access a sub-element y, it returns a 'buffer' type. What's going on? How can I access the data inside the array? Attempting y[0][1] it returns out of bounds error, and iterating through returns a strange series of 'nul' characters and yet, it appears to be able to return the first portion of the data after printing x.dataset...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` attribute of a pandas Series points to the memory buffer of all the data contained in that series:

```
>>> df = pandas.read_json('sample.json')
>>> type(df.dataset)
pandas.core.series.Series
>>> type(df.dataset.data)
memoryview
```

If you have a column/row named `"data"`, you have to access it by it's string name, e.g.:

```
>>> type(df.dataset['data'])
list
```

Because of surprises like this, it's usually considered best practice to access columns through indexing rather than through attribute access. If you do this, you will get your desired result:

```
>>> df['dataset']['data']
[['2015-10-16', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 ['2015-10-15', 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
 ['2015-10-14', 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]]

>>> arr = df['dataset']['data']
>>> arr[0][0]
'2015-10-16'
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much. Ironically, I had just been using indexed keys on a standard json import a little earlier, but hadn't thought to apply it to the pandas read :)